# Adding properties to CMake's ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK targets

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cross-compiling

I am cross-compiling with CMake through Visual Studio. The cross-compiler's platform (implemented in Visual Studio's platform property pages) requires that a specific property page be added to every project, or it will immediately fail compilation. In the nightly branch of CMake, there is a property [`VS_USER_PROPS_CXX`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/e390991846825799e619e072a28f1da58b7c89ba?w=1), which you can use to add this property sheet. This fixes both my project file, and the `INSTALL` project file.

However, this property is not applied to either the `ALL_BUILD` or `ZERO_CHECK` targets. I can set [`CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION`](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables), which will avoid any problems with `ZERO_CHECK` (while disabling re-generation within Visual Studio), but I cannot seem to do anything about `ALL_BUILD`. The consequence is that when I do: `cmake --build <project dir>`, `ALL_BUILD` will fail (even though my project succeeds).

Is there any way to either disable `ALL_BUILD` or add properties to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting the source code for CMake, it's obvious that there is no way to add additional properties to `ALL_BUILD` (or `ZERO_CHECK`), at least, not out-of-the-box. However, the source code can be modified (er... hacked), so that specific properties can be included in utility targets.

Specifically, in for the Visual Studio generator, `cmGlobalVisualStudio8Generator::AddCheckTarget` adds the `ZERO_CHECK` target, and `cmGlobalVisualStudioGenerator::AddExtraIDETargets` adds the `ALL_BUILD` target. You can modify the source code of these, and call `cmTarget::SetProperty` in the appropriate place, with the appropriate values.

If this is a requirement, it unfortunately means you need to maintain your own version of CMake.